# My Start Screen is very weird

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, vga

I have an external Monitor(1366x768) connected to my Dell Laptop(1440x900) via VGA and it works fine, other than the start screen.

These are some screen shots for you to better understand my problem.

*My monitor above my Laptop, looks fine*
[image: My monitor above my Laptop, looks fine]
*Start Screen on My monitor, weird*
[image: Start Screen on My monitor, weird]
*Start Screen on my Dell, Ideal*
[image: Start Screen on my Dell, Ideal]

How do I correct my screen on image '2'?

Comment: I'm failing to see what looks "weird" here. Any chance of a hint?

Comment: my screen is enlarged (only start screen part, sorry i was not able to explain correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Your start screen appears to be enlarged.

If you move your cursor to the right hand border of the open start screen, you will see a left/right arrow. Drag the start screen to the left until it returns to the normal Windows 7-ish style.

I myself had this problem and this fixed it.

If that was not your problem then you should have stated the exact problem more clearly.